# How to Upload Large files in Rails Application (5GB >)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, large-file-upload

I am trying to upload video files that are above 5Gb, I've implemented direct s3 upload from Heroku's documentation

`https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#jquery-file-upload-callbacks`

Everything works correctly until I press submit, after I press submit it tries to upload the file again and I get time out from Heroku. I have no idea how to fix this issue, has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: share yr work, how its being uploaded

Comment: If you’re uploading directly to S3 from the browser, how is the Heroku dyno involved?

Comment: @dbugger same implementation as Heroku article

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix the issue by changing the following

Instead of using the model related field,

```
<%= f.file_field :video %>
```

I've changed it to

```
<%= file_field_tag :video %>
```

and it works!